# How can i get response of web api in generic way in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
var ResponseData = new SingleModelResponse<UserModel>();
UserModel Model = new UserModel();
ResponseData.Model =model;
ResponseData.Message = ResponseData.Model.Message;
ResponseData.IsError = ResponseData.Model.IsError;

return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ResponseData));
```

```
using (var client2 = new HttpClient())
{
    client2.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiRequestName.BaseUrl);

    UserLoginModel td = new UserLoginModel();
    td.UserRole = "";
    td.UserName = "TestUser";
    td.Password = "test@12345";

    var postTask = client2.PostAsJsonAsync<UserLoginModel>(ApiRequestName.LoginRequest, td);
    postTask.Wait();

    var result = postTask.Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseData =result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseData))
        {
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

my response is like this

```
{
    "IsError": false,
    "ErrorMessage": null,
    "Message": "LoginSuccessful",
    "Model": {
    }
}
```

Each time I have different model. How to get this value in generic model to set value?

Comment: Most probably, the response is just a JSON. Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` to easily parse it to a type of your choice. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm

Comment: how can i take vale in model from json ?

Comment: Use `var responseData = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>()` (from `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` nuget package)